# Is this use of comma correct?

Tags: punctuation, grammar

Are the following two sentences correct? Does the comma need to be there?

Walking down the stairs, she sighed.

When he told her she had missed a form, she sighed.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you use a comma to prevent the sentence from being misread. The sentence reads easier with the comma there than without it, so I believe you're two sentences are correct.

However, there is an easier way to write them that would increase their clarity. Instead of putting a phrase before the subject and the verb, put the subject and verb first, followed by the phrase. It's just easier to read.

> She sighed as she walked down the stairs.
>
> She sighed when he told her she had missed a form.

You obviously do not have to write this way; it is just easier to read in my opinion.

Comment: However, *"My oh my," she sighed, walking down the stairs.* And *"My oh my," she sighed as she walked down the stairs.*

Comment: Yes, there are clearly several ways to write the sentence. I was just suggesting putting the subject and verb first as you did, rather than last.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use a comma after an introductory phrase.

> Walking down the stairs, she sighed.

But

> Walking down the stairs was her main form of exercise.

The second example is trickier, because the introductory phrase is more complex.

> When he told her she had missed a form, she sighed.

But the main part of the sentence is still "she sighed"—the introduction just tells us how it happened.